# glVertexAttribPointer dependant on GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am writing small library to aid me with opengl es development.
I am writing class that handles VBO.

My question is this. If I dont have OES_vertex_array_object(vertex arrays).
And use vertex buffer objects to send data to gpu. Do I have to call

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray 
glVertexAttribPointer
```

before every draw from particular VBO ? Or are these attributes saved per VBO basis. I plan to use multiple VBO's,each with its own set of attribs and shader.

From what I understand, If I have VAO , I can set up all these things once and then unbind VAO, bind another and it will have its particular set of attributes and buffers already set up from before.

Comment: opengl is a state machine, if you don't change state then it will remain the same across frames

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If you have VAOs, they track this state. Without VAOs, you have to make these calls every time you use a different VBO.

Answer (score 1):

The state set with `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()` is **not** part of the VBO.

A VBO (or any other kind of buffer) is just a data container, without much additional state. If you look up the state of a buffer object in the spec, it's basically just:

- The data itself.
- The size of the data.
- Some flags, like the *usage* value that was passed to `glBufferData()`.
- Flag that tracks if the buffer is currently mapped, and some additional state that describes the mapping if it is mapped.

This means that you have to call `glVertexAttribPointer()` every time after binding a different VBO, and before making the first draw call using the VBO.

`glEnableVertexAttribArray()` is unrelated to the current VBO binding. So if the count/location of the vertex attributes does not change, you do not need to call it again. Otherwise, you will have to enable at least the additional attributes, and disable the previously enabled attributes that are not used anymore with `glDisableVertexAttribArray()`.

Yes, making these calls again and again is kind of cumbersome. That's exactly why VAOs were added as a feature. They track all this state, and allow you to set up the entire vertex state with a single `glBindVertexArray()` call.